# How can pilots use receiver function of VOR during lost comms?

Tags: vor, lost-communications

In the event of lost comms, are pilots encouraged to try the receiver of the VOR nearby if the VOR provides the function? If they are, what's the proper use of the VOR receiver? Just tune in the VOR frequency in the VHF radio in the cockpit and listen to what ATC says and follow it? Does ATC expect pilots experiencing lost comms would use the VOR receiver as an alternate means of communications?

Comment: VOR carrier frequency [can be modulated by voice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/33747/3201) in addition of being modulated by the VOR angle signal and Morse ID. Only ATC can use such possibility, and not all VOR are capable.

Comment: @min I'm aware that not all VORs have the function, and even when they do have the function, only ATC can transmit through them. My question is: Does ATC expect pilots to monitor the frequency when they're experiencing a loss of communications?

Comment: "*Does ATC expect pilots to monitor the frequency when they're experiencing a loss of communications?*" This is answered, maybe too superficially, with reference to documentation for both ATC ([JO 7110.65 10-4-4](http://tfmlearning.faa.gov/Publications/atpubs/ATC/atc1004.html)) and pilot ([AIM 6-4-3](http://tfmlearning.fly.faa.gov/publications/atpubs/aim/Chap6/aim0604.html)).